# What does category theory have to say about formal grammar theory?

Tags: category-theory, formal-languages

It is widely believed that category theory can serve as a way of unifying various concepts.  I am interested in seeing if it can shed any light on the relationship between different formalisms which fall under the label of "grammar" - for instance, the relationship between graph grammars and matrix grammars.  Do you have any resources to recommend?